# How to access SQL server from docker ASP.net core API image

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core-webapi

I have generated a docker file for asp.net core API with a single page application thanks to Visual studio. After some research on the web I correct differents trouble about SPA in this docker file.
Finnaly my trouble is the connexion with our database server.

When I tried to connect, I've got a

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.

It seems that it appears because my container could not acces to the server, after hour and hour of google search, I only found solution with a SQL hosted in docker image.

How to all my docker image of wab app accessing the entire company network to access different server ? I use computer name ant not IP to match company requirement.

Thanks for all

Versions :

- .net core api : 3.1
- I'm using docker for Windows
- docker use linux container

Here is my docker file

```
   #See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
RUN apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install curl gnupg -yq \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash \
    && apt-get install nodejs -yq
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Company.Dtm.WebApi.AppWebApi/Company.Dtm.WebApi.AppWebApi.csproj", "Company.Dtm.WebApi.AppWebApi/"]
COPY ["CompanyFramework/Company.Framework.WebApi/Company.Framework.WebApi.csproj", "CompanyFramework/Company.Framework.WebApi/"]
COPY ["CompanyFramework/Company.Framework.Model/Company.Framework.Model.csproj", "CompanyFramework/Company.Framework.Model/"]
COPY ["CompanyFramework/Company.Framework.Tools/Company.Framework.Tools.csproj", "CompanyFramework/Company.Framework.Tools/"]
COPY ["AppLib/Company.Dtm.Lib.AppLib/Company.Dtm.Lib.AppLib.csproj", "AppLib/Company.Dtm.Lib.AppLib/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Company.Dtm.WebApi.AppWebApi/Company.Dtm.WebApi.AppWebApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Company.Dtm.WebApi.AppWebApi"
RUN dotnet build "Company.Dtm.WebApi.AppWebApi.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Company.Dtm.WebApi.AppWebApi.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Company.Dtm.WebApi.AppWebApi.dll"]
```

Here is my docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    build: .
    network_mode: "bridge"
    ports:
     - "8880:80"
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue, just trying to connect to my localhost development SQL Server.
What ended up working was to add the normal SQL Server ports to my Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 1433
EXPOSE 5000 [or whatever other ports you may be using.]
```

Then set up a firewall Inbound Rule to allow those ports.
You cannot use 'localhost' obviously since the 'localhost' is the host the container it is running in, but I did find with Windows at least, that I can simply use my dev machine name as the server, so it seems that DNS works across the nat. I would think you should be able to access any network resource at that point, but I would say your firewall[s] might be a place to start. Your Docker container acts like an external network and therefore generally un-trusted.

I also found that I did not have a 'bridge' network. Maybe you get that with the Linux container.
My >docker network ls command revealed a "Default Switch" network, but no "bridge". Because this is Docker for Windows, there is no 'host' option.

That was all there was to it for me. I see a lot of other posts talking about a lot of other things, but honestly, just opening up the firewall is what did the trick. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another service for your db in your compose file. 
Something like this:

```
version: "3"
  services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "Your_password123"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

make sure to replace the password in the `SA_PASSWORD` environment variable under `db`.

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer. But it seems that it add a SQL server in another container but that's not what I need. I need to acces my SQL server hosted in another server and not in a docker image.

Comment: Have you tried adding a SQL database connection string in your appsettings.json?

Comment: Then add this configuration in your Startup.cs in ConfigureServices method `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
      options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MssqlConnectionString")));`